# Making a Responsive Navigation Bar with content on the left, middle and right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a navigation bar that has content at the left, middle and right of the navigation bar. All these while ensuring the nav bar is still responsive. When page is minimised, a drop down menu pops out. Moreover, I am barred from using bootstrap (Homework). So how do I do it without relying on other CSS. Basically How do I create it?

I tried reading up bootstraps codes but I do not understand. Relatively rookie in terms of coding

Retrieved from W3schools

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is to make "home" on the most left of the nav bar, the "news", "content" on the center of the nav bar and lastly. The "about" on the most right of the nav bar. I want the bar to have all mentioned while still keeping the responsive function with menu when minimised.

Comment: In your HTML for the nav bar elements, start with the left ones, then the right ones, finally the center ones. Set the first two groups to `float:left` / `float:right`, center the third group. Go from there. And please try and [don't use w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com).

Comment: this dosnt help at all mate

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m9a6vx1L/

Answer (score 0):

1. I would use flexbox: ([guide on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) - it's widely supported and easy to use.
2. To start using flexbox, you have to add `display: flex` property on the parent element (`.topnav`) and `justify-content: space-between` to have child elements distributed equally on the top navbar. It will look like this:
   [image: child elements distributed equally]
3. Now, you should just group elements to three groups: left, center, right. Of course, if there is only one element on the left and right, group is needed only for middle elements (so flexbox will treat them as one child).

Something unrelated to your question: try to use more semantic HTML elements, for example, I've changed the div containing navigation links to a `nav` element: [mdn on nav element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wlecki/76ep4sov/)

Comment: This is a good solution in principle, however it will cripple the mobile menu.

Comment: @ChrisG what you mean by "cripple"? On the JSFiddle link it looks ok, but if you provide more details, I'll try to improve my solution.

Comment: If you make the result window narrow enough, the menu bar switches to responsive. The mobile menu icon no longer works, and even if you get it to work, you won't see the intended mobile menu.